# ¿Cómo enviar mensaje con bot telegram desde php en ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me funciona muy bien cuando ejecuto el codigo en windows.

`file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789130:AWERQTR-FTRE5-YUgyuGVGVggfxgxHBVCC/sendMessage?chat_id=12345678910&text=Mensaje');`

Pero al querer ejecutarlo en una pc con ubuntu hay veces que sale el mensaje y a veces no, y cuando lo hace tarda varios segundos y los mensajes llegan con un retardo de hasta 3 minutos, alguien que haya tenido el mismo problema y pueda apoyar, cabe recalcar que la función allow_url_fopen está activado en el archivo php.ini, he intentado metodos con curl que de igual forma funciona en windows pero no en ubuntu, ya que curl está instalado en la pc cuando verifico en la consola.

función curl:

```
$url="https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789130:AWERQTR-FTRE5-YUgyuGVGVggfxgxHBVCC/sendMessage?chat_id=12345678910&text=Mensaje";
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo tengo así, y me funciona de fábula:

```
$token = "123456789:AIDHjadbIDIbfpae872yr48HU137yr98y43";
$id = "987654321";

$urlMsg = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlMsg);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "chat_id={$id}&parse_mode=HTML&text=$msg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: ¿Cual fue el error/problema del OP? ¿Por qué tu respuesta funciona y no la de él? ¿Qué aprendi de bots y curl? Nada. ¿A quién le sirve esta respuesta (además del OP)? A nadie. Tienes que explicar esas cosas para que tu respuesta sea de utilidad.